# Question on the duality between necessity/knowledge and possibility

Tags: epistemology, knowledge, modal-logic

(1) Who first said that necessity and possibility are dual to each other?

(2) Who first said that knowledge and possibility are dual to each other?

Comment: For (1) see [Aristotle's Logic : Syllogisms with Modalities](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/#SylMod).

Comment: Neccessity and possibility, if I recall correctly, are formally dual in their formalisation in modal logic; but this is much later than Aristotle.